# Disconnect any VPN android ionic 3

Tags: ionic3, vpn

I am using ionic 3 and I build an app that needs to disconnect any vpn that is connected. could you please help me about it?

Comment: What did you already try and what problems did you encounter? Why would you even try to disconnect any active VPN connections?

Comment: I have tried cordova-plugin-vpn from https://github.com/aquto/cordova-plugin-vpn but Icouldn`t see any documentation about it.

Comment: I am writting an application that needs to connect to a wifi device , whenever there is a connected vpn the http requests won`t work in my application.so I want to disconnect vpn connections.

Comment: I remember seeing questions where people claim that theirs android devices can't connect to IoT devices (which provide access point for configuration purposes). Theirs handsets were able to connect to hotspot(provided by device) but were unable to connect via TCP to the device itself once they established succesfull WiFi connection to the hotspot. I wonder whether android device could indeed reject any try to connect to a local network device while it detects generic failure to connect theirs own server through such configuration wifi hotspot.